# Problems with phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, runtime-error

I have problem. When you start the application on the device.

[image]

When i press the button "back".

[image: result]

Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.firstgap"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" 
                    android:normalScreens="true" 
                    android:smallScreens="true" 
                    android:resizeable="true" 
                    android:anyDensity="true" />

            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" /> 
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" /> 
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" /> 
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> 
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
             <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" /> 
             <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
             <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" /> 
             <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" /> 
             <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" /> 
             <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" /> 
             <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" /> 
             <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
             <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
             <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" /> 
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true" >
        <activity
            android:name="org.apache.cordova.DroidGap"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"  >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.firstgap;

import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;

public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

What's the problem? Please help!!!

Comment: show your logs from logcat, we are not a wizard!

Comment: We don't need logs, we are all psychic here.

Comment: Logs are not needed, there is evident typo in Manifest :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have bad launcher activity in your Manifest try to change it to this:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.firstgap.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"  >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
<activity>
```

You have to instantiate you `com.example.firstgap.MainActivity` insthead of `org.apache.cordova.DroidGap`.